# How to create Responsive mobile supported GridView in Asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a Responsive Mobile and tablet supported Grid view in Asp.net that change its behavior on all devices and look good on each device.
I have data stored in database and also bind it to Grid View. Grid View is also showing its data. But issue is When i view this Web page in Mobile device or Tablet then some of its part is not shown or i have to scroll horizontally to see. which breaks website layout.
My Grid view code is

I have tried to use CSS property overflow:hidden; but still it is not showing me satisfactory layout in Mobile.
Thanks

Comment: You can try this link here is also code sample attach for download [http://codingresolved.com/discussion/2121/how-to-create-a-responsive-grid-view-in-asp-net-c](http://codingresolved.com/discussion/2121/how-to-create-a-responsive-grid-view-in-asp-net-c)

Comment: Thanks waqas.
I used this and this is the best solution i was finding. but in code there is no database. so i have used a database table from one of my own Db and it worked fine. Please update your code so that it can be help ful for others.

Comment: You can refer my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647751/how-to-add-responsive-behaviour-to-the-aspgridview/40647979#40647979

Answer (score 1):

CodeProject has your back.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/547745/Add-Responsive-Behaviour-to-a-GridView-in-ASP-NET

It takes the first couple of columns and then shrinks the remainder of the gridview giving the user a scroll bar.

Comment: A life-saver.  Good answer!