# How to add responsive behaviour to the asp:GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want the `asp gridview` to show responsive behaviour like the html table does with the no-more-table css style as
seen here http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/no-more-tables-respsonsive-table.

Is there a way to achieve it.

I have tried one way before, which is to replace my gridview with the html table and apply no-more-table style from
code behind. But I don't want to do this as I want to all the features offered by the `asp:GridView.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have written custom css to achieve this feature. To use my code follow the below steps,

**Step1**: Enclose your GridView inside a section with Id as no-more-gridView
as below

```
<section id="no-more-gridView">
    <asp:GridView..>
    .
    </asp:GridView>
</section>
```

**Step2**: Assign a data-title attribute to each of your cells from code behind (inside the RowDataBound function) like below,

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes["data-title"] = "Col1Name";
e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes["data-title"] = "Col2Name";
e.Row.Cells[2].Attributes["data-title"] = "Col3Name";
.
.
```

**Step3**:  Finally include my custom style given below. Use `media query` to apply the style at whatever screen size you wish it to come to effect and that should pretty much do the trick.

```
/*  Author     : Vinay
    Description: Responsive GridView
*/

    /* Force gridview to not be like gridview anymore */
    #no-more-gridView table, 
    #no-more-gridView thead, 
    #no-more-gridView tbody, 
    #no-more-gridView th, 
    #no-more-gridView td, 
    #no-more-gridView tr { 
        display: block; 
    }
    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    #no-more-gridView .table_column_head > * { 
        display:none;
    }
    #no-more-gridView tr { all: revert;border: 2px solid #ccc;height:auto !important;}
    #no-more-gridView td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%; 
        white-space: normal;
        text-align:left;
        padding-bottom: 1em;
    }
    #no-more-gridView td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align:left;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    /*
    Label the data
    */
    #no-more-gridView td:before { content: attr(data-title); }
```

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: I had to add the following CSS code to make my gridview's headers hide:
 
    `#no-more-gridView th { display: none; }`

Comment: @SantiagoTrejo Glad you pointed it out. I had left it out so that anyone using this style can customize the header as needed (As It was a requirement for many of my grids , such as keeping just the SelectAll check box visible in the header in responsive view - making my task easier)